# Active Admin before filter for namespace only

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

I have a namespace `admin`. I would like to apply a `before_filter` only to this namespace (not the default one, which is `superuser`).

I can add the following code in `active_admin.rb`

```
ns.before_filter :is_subscribed?
```

But then, the `superuser` gets the filter too.

I tried adding the `before_filter` inside my namespace configuration :

```
config.namespace :admin do |ns|
  ...
  ns.before_filter :is_subscribed?
end
```

but Rails throws an error :

```
undefined method `before_filter' for #<ActiveAdmin::Namespace:0x007fa2e0f75f00>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add a controller with that before_filter then in all the controllers in that namespace inherit from that controller?

Ie. AdminBaseController.

Comment: Sounds like a sensible solution. However, it means I will have to add inheritance for all my resources... I would much prefer adding a filter inside the namespace config. Why isn't it working?

Comment: I don't think it is possible to do so. Someone more experienced can confirm I guess.

Answer (score 0):

I would have a file `active_admin_extension.rb` in admin directory with the content like this:

```
module ActiveAdmin
  class BaseController
    before_filter :make_sure_something

    private
    def make_sure_something
      if active_admin_namespace.name == :my_desired_namespace && !something_there
         #do something here
      end
    end
  end
end
```